# How do I fill the authors name in a term reference field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules

Content type `stock` contains the term reference field `field_producer`. What is the rule for [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in order to fill this field with the node author name on creation?

### In detail

**The form looks like:**

-- Content type **Stock** (`stock`)

---- field **Producer** (`field_producer`); of field type *Term reference*; of widget *Autocomplete term widget (tagging)*; number of values: *1*; Vocabulary: *Producer*

**The goal is:**

When a user creates a node of the type *Stock*, his user name should automatically be filled/(pre-)populated in the field *Producer*.

**Why Rules:**

Since tokens aren't working for the autocomplete term reference field and a text field isn't available, rules might be a workaround. I've tried Prepopulate, Entityreference prepopulate, and other modules, but none of them supported the aim.

**Where I am struggling with Rules:**

- Event: *After saving new content*, Restrict by type *Stock*
- Condition: *Entity has field*, Data selector *node:field-producer*, Field Value *field_producer*
- Action: *Set a data value*, Data (to be modified) *node:field-producer*, **Value (to set for the specified data): HERE REMAINS THE PROBLEM. I can't choose node:author or other tokens that display the user name. I get the restriction: "Data types: Select data of the type Taxonomy term."**

That's why I am not able to successfully create this rule.

What am I doing wrong? How should this rule look like?

Comment: Creation of a node from the type "Stock". I was able to successfully use "After saving new content of type Stock", but I can't make it work with the data types. I get a restriction like "Data types: Select data of the type Taxonomy term." or the added token [node:author] has no effect. What I am trying to do is to use Rules in order to automatically fill the name of a node author as a taxonomy term for the vocabulary "Producer" in the field "field_producer" (so that the author doesn't have to do it manually).

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question to integrate the prior comment (it clarifies your question a little bit). And also explain (via edit, not extra comments) these things: (1) how does that vocabulary look like (does the term "node author" exist already and is it a single value field) (2) what's the machine name of that field of your content type that you want to "automatically fill", and is it a single or multi value field (3) include an export of the rule you already have so far (even if it doesn't work yet)

Answer (score 0):

> ... I can't choose node:author or other tokens that display the user name. I get the restriction: "Data types: Select data of the type Taxonomy term."

### 1. Switch to the direct input mode

You should click the <kbd>Switch to the direct input mode</kbd> button (near the bottom left), which looks like this:

[image]

After clicking that button, it will bring up a selection list of the ***available*** terms (= possible values) that you can use in your taxonomy field.

### 2. Example

Consider this example, in Rules Export format, of a rule (actually a Rules Component, but the idea is the same) to illustrate how such Rules Action to "***Set a data value***" should look like and which will set the value of the term reference field `field_sample_tags` to term id = `31`:

```
{ "rules_replace_a_term_field_by_another_term_field" : {
    "LABEL" : "Replace a term field by another term field",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_sample_tags" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_demo_tags" } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-demo-tags" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-sample-tags" ], "value" : "31" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Term updated in node with id = [node:nid]" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details to explain the above prototype:

- It uses a node as a parameter (to execute the Rules Component).
- These are the Rules Conditions:

  - check if the entity (= node) has a field `field_sample_tags`.
  - check if the entity (= node) has a field `field_demo_tags`.
  - check if the value of the field `field_demo_tags` corresponds to the term we want to replace (in this example, the term has id = `1`).
- These are the Rules Actions:

  - Set the value of field `field_sample_tags` equal to the term with term id = `31` (which is the term in the vocabulary for which we want to add the term reference).
  - Display a message on the site (only used for demo / testing).

### 3. Improvement - Pick the existing term that fits

Your question doesn't say "*How to pick the appropriate term (i.e. its term id) to be used to perform the 'Set a data value' for a given node author (how can you derive that term id from the data about the node author)?*".

If you only have a few node authors (say "Xin" and "Pierre"), you could use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to improve that Rules Action to 'Set a data value', so that the value to be used for the term id depends on the value of the node author.

### 4. Open question

Your question doesn't say "*What should happen if no term exists yet for a specific node author?*". If such scenario is impossible in your site, then you're lucky (and good to go). Otherwise you'll have to further improve the Rules logic you're implementing to:

1. get the appropriate (new) term created on the fly.
2. go find out what the term id is for the newly created term.
3. improve the Rules Action to 'Set a data value' to actually use the term id of this newly created term.

If you wonder how to do that (also), use [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ... 3 times (one for every bullet).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Pierre. To get to your points: Using "Selected data: node:field-producer" in Action, I just get "Taxonomy term identifier" when switching to direct input mode (without any possibility to add tokens). I still want the functionality of the _Autocomplete term widget (tagging)_, meaning choose existing term or add new one. I just don't want the users, old ones with an exiting term and new ones without, to fill their username manually in this field. I want the equivalent of node:author or site:current-user in this field and let taxonomy/term reference work.

Comment: @XinNod most of my answer is an answer to "*What am I doing wrong?*" (as in your question). The additional answer to your "*How should this rule look like?*" (as in your question also) is like: even though I do NOT consider myself as a Rules expert (I'm not Fago ... or Johan Falk), to my knowledge there is no way you can make that to happen with **Rules**. And the same applies to most of your previous comment. So with that, maybe you do want to consider marking this answer as "accepted", and then post a followup-question (linked to here) like "if Rules cannot do this, how else can I do it?".